# create a python function as store_id & date as input and output as the previous date's sales

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filtering, grouping, datetime-format

I have this `store_df` DataFrame:

```
store_id    date    sales
0   1   2023-1-2    11
1   2   2023-1-3    22
2   3   2023-1-4    33
3   1   2023-1-5    44
4   2   2023-1-6    55
5   3   2023-1-7    66
6   1   2023-1-8    77
7   2   2023-1-9    88
8   3   2023-1-10   99
```

I am not able to solve this in the interview.

This was the exact question asked :

1. Create a dataset with 3 columns – store_id, date, sales Create 3 Store_id Each store_id has 3 consecutive dates Sales are recorded for 9 rows We are considering the same 9 dates across all stores Sales can be any random number
2. Write a function that fetches the previous day’s sales as output once we give store_id & date as input

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update the question with your own attempt to reach the desired result and let us know where specifically you run into issues. See [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).
SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: If the days are always consecutive, then a simple answer is: `store_df['prev_day_sales'] = store_df.groupby('store_id')['sales'].shift()`

Comment: store_df['prev_day_sales'] = store_df.groupby('store_id')['sales'].shift()   This has given me a new column thats good. Now how do i extract the value from the data frame with the given date and store id

Answer (score 0):

The question can be handled in multiple ways.

If you want to just get the previous row per group, assuming that the values are consecutive and sorted by increasing dates, use a [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
store_df['prev_day_sales'] = store_df.groupby('store_id')['sales'].shift()
```

Output:

```
   store_id       date  sales  prev_day_sales
0         1 2023-01-02     11             NaN
1         2 2023-01-02     22             NaN
2         3 2023-01-02     33             NaN
3         1 2023-01-03     44            11.0
4         2 2023-01-03     55            22.0
5         3 2023-01-03     66            33.0
6         1 2023-01-04     77            44.0
7         2 2023-01-05     88            55.0
8         3 2023-01-04     99            66.0
```

If, you really want to get the **previous day**'s value (not the previous available day), use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
store_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(store_df['date'])

store_df.merge(store_df.assign(date=lambda d: d['date'].add(pd.Timedelta('1D'))),
               on=['store_id', 'date'], suffixes=(None, '_prev_day'), how='left'
              )
```

*Note. This makes it easy to handle other deltas, like business days (replace `pd.Timedelta('1D')` with `pd.offsets.BusinessDay(1)`).*

Example (with a different input):

```
   store_id       date  sales  sales_prev_day
0         1 2023-01-02     11             NaN
1         2 2023-01-02     22             NaN
2         3 2023-01-02     33             NaN
3         1 2023-01-03     44            11.0
4         2 2023-01-03     55            22.0
5         3 2023-01-03     66            33.0
6         1 2023-01-04     77            44.0
7         2 2023-01-05     88             NaN # there is no data for 2023-01-04
8         3 2023-01-04     99            66.0
```

Comment: Where can I get these kind of interview questions to practice?